# ext4 mount flags for 10+ mill files storage

Tags: filesystems, mount, ext4

I've initialised one large primary partition with the `-T small` flag to `mke2fs`, `small` on the system is configured as follows:

```
    small = {
            blocksize = 1024
            inode_size = 128
            inode_ratio = 4096
    }
```

This is a 800 GB SSD (cloud drive) which will be a home for the 10+ million small files, ranging from ~10KB to ~100KB.

I tried to go thoroughly the man pages of `mount` and figure out the best combo of flags and here's my list:

- `rw` - *read and write*
- `nosuid` - *no need for user or group  ID  on  execution*
- `nodev` - *block dev files should never appear in here*
- `noexec` - *files with exec bit set are also not welcome*
- `auto` - *allow `mount -a`*
- `nouser` - *only `root` can (re)mount*
- `async` - *async writing*
- `relatime` - *update access time only when files are modified.*
- `data=ordered` - *presumably should improve read performance*
- `errors=remount-ro` - *stop writing when errors*
- `discard` - *recommended for SSD*
- `auto_da_alloc` - *fight filesystem corruption in case of power failure (perhaps not needed, as this is a cloud drive?)*
- `inode_readahead_blks=16` - *file system will be a home for the great bunch of small files, hence big readahead should be nothing more but a performance penalty. I didn't know the optimal value for files of average size 50KB, so just put here twice as less value as the default.*
- `debug`

I really need a second opinion from someone more experienced in these matters. I'm particularly unsure about the `discard`, `relatime`, `data=ordered`, `auto_da_alloc`, `inode_readahead_blks` and other flags, which I have missed or misunderstood. How dangerous is `data=writeback`? How much data I may loose with such flag, is it just the last 5 sec (default value of commit)? Other insight regarding this exercise?

Comment: Why have you chosen ext4 for your filesystem?

Comment: My playground here is the production server, hence I need `fs` that was well tested by many and proven being stable and efficient.

Comment: What kind of storage controller are you on?  Is it battery backed? This will have a pretty significant impact on some flags you can/cannot safely use that may have some pretty big performance impacts.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably [just use the XFS filesystem](https://serverfault.com/q/688438/13325) for this.

ext4 is not well-suited to this workload because you're on an SSD and have a stupid-high file count. There's a reason Red Hat [now defaults to XFS](https://www.redhat.com/f/pdf/RHEL6_FileSystem_WP_5677547_0311_dm_web.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, but based on [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28792/111103), `XFS` perhaps is the last thing I should use for the great number of small files, unless you can argue these results.

Comment: ***Do what you want...*** or just test with your own data set.

Comment: Your statement that I should just use `XFS` is not very convincing, especially when there's evidence showing otherwise...

Comment: Okay, then you've arrived at your own conclusion.

Comment: @NarūnasK *Your statement that I should just use XFS is not very convincing*  And that benchmark you linked to isn't very convincing, either.  Benchmarks that don't specify the hardware being used are useless.

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider using ZFS on linux? ZFS is definetly superior to ext4 and it's considered production ready on linux. See http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTc4NTM

It's not difficult to install; see http://zfsonlinux.org/ for installation info.

Comment: Thank you for your input. `zfs` was noted and expelled from the list due to the fact, that it is not supported in Debian (because of the licensing) and its greedy constraints of the memory. I agree, that `zfs` is superior system and RAM these days is relatively cheap, however decisions already made.

Comment: @NarūnasK *`zfs` was noted and expelled from the list due to the fact, that it is not supported in Debian (because of the licensing)*  So you've already decided on your solution and you're now force-fitting your problems into that solution.  That's backwards.

Comment: No, these answers just don't answer his question. He didn't ask for another file system. He asked about the flags for mounting the file system he's already chosen.